# What does array_diff_uassoc() function do in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to php and i have read the documentation about **array_diff_uassoc()** function on **php.net**, **w3schools** and on other resources on the internet but failed to get what is the use of this function. According to me it is non sense function because its its documentation is so confusing.

As i know first parameter and second parameters are arrays, but what does third parameter do it takes function and it must return less than , greater than or equal to 0 and this and this. What does this nonsense documentation means ?

Following all the examples generate same result.

**Example 1**

```
function test($a,$b){
$a > $b ? 1 : -1;
}

$arrayOne = array(
    "one"=>"elementOne",
    "two"=>"elementTwo",
    "three"=>"elementThree"
);

$arrayTwo = array(
    "one"=>"elementOne",
    "two"=>"elementTwo",
    "three"=>"elementThree"
);

$x = array_diff_uassoc($arrayOne,$arrayTwo,'test');
```

**Output**

> Array
>   (
>       [two] => elementTwo
>       [three] => elementThree
>   )

**Example 2**

```
function test($a,$b){
$a > $b ? -1 : 1;
}

$arrayOne = array(
    "one"=>"elementOne",
    "two"=>"elementTwo",
    "three"=>"elementThree"
);

$arrayTwo = array(
    "one"=>"elementOne",
    "two"=>"elementTwo",
    "three"=>"elementThree"
);

$x = array_diff_uassoc($arrayOne,$arrayTwo,'test');
```

**Output**

> Array
>   (
>       [two] => elementTwo
>       [three] => elementThree
>   )

**Example 3**

```
function test($a,$b){
$a < $b ? 0 : 1;
}

$arrayOne = array(
    "one"=>"elementOne",
    "two"=>"elementTwo",
    "three"=>"elementThree"
);

$arrayTwo = array(
    "one"=>"elementOne",
    "two"=>"elementTwo",
    "three"=>"elementThree"
);

$x = array_diff_uassoc($arrayOne,$arrayTwo,'test');
```

**Output**

> Array
>   (
>       [two] => elementTwo
>       [three] => elementThree
>   )

**Example 4**

```
function test($a,$b){
$a < $b ? 0 : 1;
}

$arrayOne = array(
    "one"=>"elementOne",
    "two"=>"elementTwo",
    "three"=>"elementThree"
);

$arrayTwo = array(
    "one"=>"elementOne",
    "two"=>"elementTwo",
    "three"=>"elementThree"
);

$x = array_diff_uassoc($arrayOne,$arrayTwo,'test');
```

**Output**

> Array
>   (
>       [two] => elementTwo
>       [three] => elementThree
>   )

So what does this nonsense function means ? Can anyone tell or may be i am wrong ?

Comment: Your `test` function doesn’t follow the rules you listed. You shouldn’t expect it to have the correct results. Careful labelling things as “nonsense” just because you don’t understand them, that’s not the best way to approach learning

Comment: So should i must follow the same documentation as documented on the internet ?

Comment: Please can you do a few examples in separate answer ?  I will mark your question if it clear my concept.

Comment: `The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.`: Well if the [PHPDocs page](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php) says that the user calback function should return a value, then it's always a good idea for your callback function to return a value

Comment: Please don't provide outlines in comment. Do a separate answer with examples please

Comment: There’s no “must”, do what you need to do. The documentation is clear to me, so yes, I’d use that personally. But you’re basically saying “the documentation says to do it one way, but when I do it another way, the results are confusing”. To which I think most would reply “well yeah, of course”.

Comment: Ok let suppose function return 0 or 1 or -1. So what will happen ?

Comment: It’s a comparison function, it compares - if you don’t know what it’s for I don’t understand why you’re so intent on using it? Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php, especially the Return Values section. That should help to clear it up

Comment: Then what is the purpose of using this function in third parameter?

Comment: The comparison function allows you to create custom logic to determine whether the two entries are the same or not

Comment: To provide a custom function for the comparison. It’s what the “u” stands for (user-defined) and the only difference between this function and array_diff_assoc. If you still don’t understand the purpose of the function from that, it would probably be best just not to use it. You’d know if you had a use case for it

Comment: @markbaker - You mean it does not effect the array comparison. It only allow us to create custom logic for our own use in our own way.

Comment: @Clive - Can you do one example as answer that define the use case for this function ?

Comment: There are several on the php.net docs page, I don’t really see value in copying them over here

Comment: NO!!!! The comparison function that you provide is what determines if there is a difference between pairs of elements or not.... it ___is___ the comparison

Comment: Ok so what will happen if 0 is returned, what will happen if 1 is returned and what will happen if -1 is returned ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison function allows you to create custom logic to determine whether the two entries are the same or not.

The keys in these two arrays look totally different, because they are in different languages.

```
$data1 = [
  'red' => true,
  'yellow' => true,
  'green' => true,
  'blue' => true,
  'black' => true,
];

$data2 = [
  'rouge' => true,
  'jaune' => true,
  'bleu' => true,
  'vert' => true,
  'blanc' => true,
];
```

But we can still do a diff against them using a custom comparison function that recognises where the two languages have equivalent values

```
function colourLanguageTest($a, $b) {
    static $comparator = [
        'red' => 'rouge',
        'yellow' => 'jaune',
        'green' => 'vert',
        'blue' => 'bleu',
        'black' => 'noir',
        'white' => 'blanc',
    ];

    if (isset($comparator[$a])) {
        return $comparator[$a] != $b;
    } elseif(isset($comparator[$b])) {
        return $comparator[$b] != $a; 
    }

    return true;
}

$result = array_diff_uassoc($data1, $data2, 'colourLanguageTest');

var_dump($result);
```

The comparison function checks for the entries in the comparator table, so it can identify that `red` and `rouge` are the same, and treat them as a match. A boolean false (`0`) will be returned if there is a match a boolean true (`1`) if there is no match.
Because this is a diff function, it filters out all entries from the first array where our custom logic returns 0 (indicating a match) and leaves only entries where our comparison logic doesn't return a 0 (ie returns 1 or -1 or 999 or -23456)

Because 'red', 'yellow', 'green' and 'blue' all have corresponding entries in the second array that match according to the language lookup, only 'black' doesn't have a corresponding entry in the second data array, so the result of our call to `array_diff_uassoc()` returns

```
array(1) {
  ["black"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok so what will happen if 0 is returned, what will happen if 1 is returned and what will happen if -1 is returned ? And what will happen if anything other than 0, 1 and -1 is returned ?

Comment: I marked your question only for that 0 means matched, 1 mean not matched in the context of this function. But didn't get you. Anyways thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

there must be a return value in your callback "test" function

```
function test($a,$b){

   if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b)? 1:-1;
}

$arrayOne = array(
    "one"=>"elementOne",
    "two"=>"elementTwo",
    "three"=>"elementThree"
);

$arrayTwo = array(
    "one"=>"elementOne",
    "two"=>"elementTwo",
    "three"=>"elementThree"
);
```

Comment: Ok let suppose function return 0 or 1 or -1. So what will happen ?